# realpath couldn't resolve "/usr/bin/-perl" on Mac Terminal

Tags: macos, perl, terminal

I'm trying to install Tails on my Mac using this instruction guide (https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/installation/manual/mac/index.en.html) and I've been successful up to step 4, sub-step 6 where it says "To run isohybrid.pl on the ISO image, execute the following command, replacing [tails.iso] with the path to the ISO image that you want to install."

Below is my terminal window. I have no idea what a majority of this means and this is actually my first time ever using terminal. I was able to figure out how to check my hidden bin folder through finder and I checked for -perl and I didn't see that file in there. I saw perl, perlbug, perldoc, etc. but no -perl. Also I'm confused as to if this command actually did something because the 'couldn't resolve' message and the '[Process completed]' message seem kind of contradictory. Anyway, if anyone could help me get unstuck, that would be great :)

Here is a screenshot of my terminal window: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hmc8c.png

Comment: … because it should be `/usr/bin/perl` or something like that (without the hyphen). Did you make the error, or did the script contain the mistake?

Comment: I think the script must have contained the mistake. Is there an easy way to go in and fix that?

Comment: Given you have "process completed" immediately after the error message, I am inclined to believe you double-clicked on the script (within Finder) to run it. Is that the case?